# PHP logging in all caps

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I created a PHP Login and Register page. I just registered my name = 'ajnaidas' and it saved in database as is. but when I tried to login as 'AJNAIDAS' with all caps, my login still accepts it. . . does anyone have an idea how to fix this? tnx!

Comment: You should post the code that you already have.

Comment: It's entirely dependent on the PHP code of the login page.  Can you post that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Likely the collation setting for the username column in your database is set to a `*_ci` (case insensitive) collation. Set it to a `_bin` or other case *sensitive* collation if you require matches without fuzzing.